# Как сделать icontains нечувствительным к регистру c SQLite?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Как обходить проблему чувствительности лукапа icontains при использовании SQLite?

```py
User.objects.create(name='Василий')

query = 'василий'

User.objects.filter(name__icontains=query) # <QuerySet []>
```

Comment: Нужна регистрозависимая проверка?

Comment: @Александр наоборот, регистронезависимая

Comment: @Александр единственный вариант, который приходит в голову, сделать полную выборку и по очереди проверять каждый элемент, приведя все к нижнему регистру. Но что-то подсказывает, что это плохой вариант)

Comment: у вас в бд только первые буквы могут быть заглавными или непредсказуемо?

Comment: я не могу это сейчас проверить, но нашел в оф доке такой комментарий, касающийся sqlite: ` For substring matching, all matches are done case-insensitively. That is a filter such as filter(name__contains="aa") will match a name of "Aabb".`. Если ему верить, то contains должен работать регистронезависимо

Comment: @Александр подозреваю, что на русские буквы это не распространяется) Но сейчас попробую проверить.

Comment: @Александр в БД регистр может быть непредсказуемым

Comment: @Александр да, это работает только с английским буквами

Comment: да, видимо, вы правы и это не распространяется только unicode

Comment: На оф сайте sqlite предлагают использовать спец расширение icu и использовать функцию lower() в sql-запросе. Пожалуй, это самое оптимальное с тз производительности, но довольно тяжёлое. Можно ещё как вариант, при сохранении все переводить в нижний регистр с добавлением спец.символа, и при чтении снова переводить в верхний, удаляя его - первое, что пришло в голову. Но на больших текстах это может так же повлечь за собой оверхэд

Comment: @Александр можно в принципе сделать отдельное поле для хранения отдельно значения, приведенного к нижнему регистру. Но что-то все равно колхоз, видимо, придется переехать на postres)

Answer (score 1):

Простой ответ: никак. ILIKE - это специфическая особенность Postgres. Но если очень хочется, то

```
from django.db.models.functions import Upper

User.objects.create(name='Василий')

query = 'василий'

User.objects.annotate(
  uppered_name=Upper('name')
).filter(uppered_name__icontains=upper(query)) # <QuerySet [User(name='Василий')]>
```

Надеюсь, это поможет.